# Type hinting in JSON deserialization

Tags: c#, .net, json, deserialization, datacontract

I have been using an `ASP.NET` (asmx) `WebService` to communicate with a server via `AJAX`. I am now currently using complex types in my `WebMethods`. My issue is that one of my classes has a property with a type that is an interface.

When serialising everything is fine as the instance type is known. Upon deserialising the `JSON` converter does not know the type to convert to as it cannot create an instance of my Interface. So I took a look at [Type Hinting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412170(v=vs.110).aspx) specifically the polymorphism section, I have been trying to get this working but no luck.

Here's a sample of my code:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")] 
[ScriptService]
public class MyService : System.Web.Services.WebService {

    public MyService () { }

    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    [ScriptMethod]
    public void SaveThing(Thing myThing) 
    {
        //Do stuff
    }
}

public interface IItem : ISerializable
{
    int Id { get; }
    string Options { get; }
}

[DataContract(Namespace="MyNamespace", Name="Item")]
public class Item : IItem
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Url
    {
        get { return m_url; }
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class Thing
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IItem MyItem { get; set; }
}
```

I get the `__type` attribute for `myThing (Thing)` upon serialization of the but not for the property `MyItem (Item)`. I've tried forcing it by manipulating the `JSON` and sending it back but I just get `InvalidServiceOperation`. Am I attempting something that is not allowed? The MSDN documentation does not seem to mention I cannot deserialise to an interface using type hinting for the instantiation, but its example does imply classes and derived classes.

If possible I would like to continue using attributes for serialization rather than custom code, just because I think it's neater. Still open to coded solutions though.

Answer (score 1):

Right, after more searching and research I came up with a solution, it's not as tidy and *nice* as I wanted, but it works.

Firstly what didn't work. So I tried using `ISerializable`, Implemented my class with `GetObjectData()` and a deserialisation constructor:

```
[Serializable]
public class Thing : ISerializable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IItem MyItem { get; set; }

    public Thing(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context){
    {
        //Do deserialization and handle IItem object
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        //Do serialization
    }
}
```

Now I think this didn't work because all the properties of `Thing` get deserialised before this constructor is called, causing the native serialiser to attempt to deserialise my interface.

On to what did work. Custom `JavascriptConverter` to the rescue. So I changed my webservice to take a string as a parameter instead of a complex object (the bit I don't really like), then Implemented a `JavascriptConverter` with a known type of `IItem` to handle the deserialisation into a concrete class.

```
public class ItemConverter : JavaScriptConverter
{
    public override IEnumerable<Type> SupportedTypes
    {
        get { return new List<Type>() { typeof(IItem) }; }
    }

    public override IDictionary<string, object> Serialize(object obj, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object Deserialize(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        //If we are of type IItem
        if (dictionary.ContainsKey("Type")) //My check to make sure we are of type IItem
        {
            var factory = new ItemFactory();
            return factory.CreateItem((int)dictionary["Id"], (string)dictionary["Options"], (ItemTypes)dictionary["Type"]);
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")] 
[ScriptService]
public class MyService : System.Web.Services.WebService {

    public MyService () { }

    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    [ScriptMethod]
    public void SaveThing(string myThing) 
    {
        //Get our custom converter
        var itemConverter = new ItemConverter();
        var serialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        //Register it
        serialiser.RegisterConverters(new List<JavaScriptConverter>() { itemConverter });
        //Deserialise the dashboard
        var theThing = serialiser.Deserialize<Thing>(myThing);

        //Save
        theThing.Save();
    }
}
```

I hope this helps somebody, and if anybody has any more elegant solutions, I would love to see them. Also on a side note, throughout this I didn't want to have any dependencies on third party libraries such as `Json.NET` or `NewtonSoft JSON` etc.